# MySql, Sqlite, Wix; Opinions, Suggestions, Ideas

Tags: mysql, sqlite, wix

Currently I am working on a project, which uses a server base MySql to save some test results from equipments they make, and program works fine and at each test end it uses saved data to generate report with results. My client wants to use the same program in technicians laptops so they can visit various sites but there is no connectivity to the server. For the moment there is no requirement these needs to synchronise. But there will be time my client say he needs it. So I have to do it keep that in mind.

I have discussed this with my colleagues and they also come up with different ideas.

**Idea 1** Use a small config tool to determine which version user wants and if user runs outside the network use a SQLite as a local database.

**Problems :**

- I have to use different codes as SQLite and MySql functions are different such as Date Functions & etc.
- When its come to Synchronise will their be any limitations.

** Idea 2** Install MySql in the host computer after determining from users weather it needs to be install server based or local version.

**Problems & Doubts :**

- Will MySql slow the host computers because laptop computers actually technicions work stations. They do not need MySql services to run all time time ?
- Can Wix Scripts written to install MySql and create the tables or is it need to manually all the time for the pc to pc. If so any examples.

Any ideas, opinions suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

WiX only has built in support for MS Sql Server.  I have no idea what youare using to develop your solution but if your doing .NET and choose to go with Sql Server Compact Edition you should be able to  use MS Sync Services to provide for a pretty good offline data input and sync capability while also greatly simplifying your deployment story with WiX as you don't really have to execute sql scripts to create your databases.

Comment: Hi Chris ! Problem is 1st phase is already done in MySql. and its up and running. That is why I am struggling with. Thanks for your idea, it will greatly help for my future projects.

Comment: As an aside, InstallShield has support for executing SQL scripts against MySQL.  No such support for SqlLite.  You might have to end up writing custom actions or removing the database setup from your installer and putting it into a post-install configuration utility.